# Можно ли к массиву string добавить еще несколько строк?

Tags: stl, c++

Например, есть `string Array[40]`, а мне надо добавить еще несколько элементов. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В STL есть класс vector - массив, который динамически меняет свой размер:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

main() {
    vector<string> nums;

    nums.push_back("first");
    nums.push_back("second");
    nums.push_back("third");

    for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
       cout << nums[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: А как получить один символ какой-нибудь строки?

Comment: Например, так: nums[i][j]; nums[0][0] - это 'f', а nums[2][2] - это 'i'.

Comment: Отлично! Все работает! Спасибо!

ps Отличный сайт.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос: для динамического добавления надо использовать классы лист или вектор.

Comment: Ты правильно понял. Только не хочется весь код переделывать под лист или вектор. Я использовал string.h. Уже почти всю лабу сделал, а там надо добавить несколько записей. Пробывал с vector, только были проблемы с vector< vector<char*> >. Или как еще можно сделать массив строк через вектор?

Answer (score 0):

В c есть функция realloc. Для минимизации переделок возможно и подходящий вариант.
Только вот смешение new/delete с malloc/free может вызывать проблемы, так что надо обратить внимание на этот момент.

Comment: смешение будет в перекрещивающихся указателях.